# where clause in VBA doesn't return what I need

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to filter a dataset that I am pulling in from access using VBA, but for some reason this code doesn't return the filtered results.

```
  With BrokerData
        .ActiveConnection = BrokerConn
        .Source = "SELECT * FROM BP_Closed_Deals WHERE EMM_Name = 'JM' OR 'J-C E';"
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .Open
    End With
```

Comment: `WHERE EMM_Name = 'JM' OR EMM_Name = 'J-C E'`

Comment: `WHERE EMM_Name IN ('JM', 'J-C E')` or `WHERE EMM_Name = 'JM' OR EMM_Name = 'J-C E'`

Answer (score 2):

The following is not valid SQL syntax:

```
WHERE EMM_Name = 'JM' OR 'J-C E'
```

You want:

```
WHERE EMM_Name = 'JM' OR EMM_Name = 'J-C E'
```

Which can also be expressed with the `IN` operator:

```
WHERE EMM_Name IN ('JM', 'J-C E')
```